# How to find the degree cover of a path-connected space with an infinite simple fundamental group

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $X$ be a path-connected space with fundamental group $G$, where $G$ is an infinite simple group. Prove that $X$ has no finite degree cover of degree more than $1$.

I know that $G$ has no normal subgroups other that $\{1\}$ and $G$. But how do I go about proving the statement?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: if a group has a proper subgroup of finite index then it has a proper normal subgroup of finite index. To see this, let $H$ be a proper subgroup of $G$ with $n = (G:H)$ finite. The action of $G$ on the left cosets of $H$ induces a homorphism of $G$ into a non-trivial subgroup of $S_n$. The kernel of this homomorphism is a proper normal subgroup of finite index.